# How to use AbpSession?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I want to use `AbpSession` in my custom repository, but I can't get the instance. I want to extend `DataFilter` on Entity Framework Core + .NET Core 2.1, what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already answered your question in comment. You have to declare a member of type `IAbpSession` and initialise it with the value in the constructor. You can then use the `UserId`, `TenantId`..... properties accordingly.

```
public class MyClass : ITransientDependency
{
    public IAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var currentUserId = AbpSession.UserId;
        //...
    }
}
```

You can refer the documentation [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Abp-Session).

Comment: I used you comment code because the class must have IAbpSession, Not NullAbpSession,Thank you for your answer.If the user is not logged in web，
I don't want him to use this class。

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation on [Abp Session](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Abp-Session):

```cs
public class MyClass : ITransientDependency
{
    public IAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var currentUserId = AbpSession.UserId;
        //...
    }
}
```